# Não consigo trazer todos os registros da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, query

Olá, não estou conseguindo mostrar todos os registros de uma linha da tabela do BD, só consigo trazer o primeiro registro.

Aqui está a minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbnoticiasrel` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_noticia` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`id_noticia_relacionada` int(20),
`id_noticia_relacionada1` int(20),
`id_noticia_relacionada2` int(20),
`id_noticia_relacionada3` int(20),
 `id_noticia_relacionada4` int(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Aqui são os meus registros na tabela ( no modo admin do site )
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o meu select no script php:

```
 $query_noticiasrelacionadas = "SELECT * "
                        . "FROM tbnoticiasrel AS nr "
                        . "INNER JOIN tbnews AS n ON nr.id_noticia_relacionada = n.id "
                        . "WHERE nr.id_noticia = " . $_REQUEST[idNoticia];
```

aqui está o resultado da query (acima):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
sim, esta trazendo somente um dado das 5 relacionadas.
o que pode ser?

Comment: já testou LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Sim, já testei e o resultado é o mesmo tanto quanto para o RIGHT JOIN

Comment: Esse `WHERE nr.id_noticia = " . $_REQUEST[idNoticia]` não deveria ser `WHERE n.id_noticia = " . $_REQUEST[idNoticia]` ?

Comment: Então deixa eu te perguntar uma coisa. Esse campo nr.id_noticia é comum entre as duas tabelas? Porque no ON vc está chamando uma relação diferente. E no caso se nr.id_noticia não tiver nas duas tabelas, as demais serão ignoradas.

Comment: Não, o where está pedindo que Quando o id_noticia (da noticia principal que esta sendo relacionada) for igual a notícia que está na requisição.

sim, o id_noticia da tabela nr é igual ao campo id da tabela n.

Comment: Pelo que entendo, você quer chamar o conteúdo por uma outra id, mas que se relacionam por outros valores, o problema disso vai ser no union, o "where" só vai traz conteúdo que tiver nr.id_noticia = valor_buscado, ele não vai trazer noticias que foram relacionadas por outra condição a menos que ambas tenham o mesmo valor relacionado... deu pra entender?

Comment: Para Testar, tira a condição WHERE e executa sua query no phpmyadmin ou workbench, veja se ele está trazendo toda as notícias com nr.id_noticia que vc quer trazer na listagem. Tem que dar duplicidade ou mais na nr.id_noticia

Answer (score 1):

Cara, 
Creio que o problema esteja justamente no join, visto que ele não retorna dados se não houver correspondência nas duas tabelas, tente utilizar LEFT OUTER JOIN ao invés de INNER JOIN ou LEFT JOIN somente.

Seria algo como:

```
$query_noticiasrelacionadas = "SELECT * "
                    . "FROM tbnoticiasrel AS nr "
                    . "LEFT OUTER JOIN tbnews AS n ON nr.id_noticia_relacionada = n.id "
                    . "WHERE nr.id_noticia = " . $_REQUEST[idNoticia];
```

Espero que ajude